# Custom keyboard and type letters

Tags: iphone, sdk, keyboard

every one  i create custom keyboard and i have problem 
iam using my keyboard as `textview.inputView = myKeyboardView;`
my keyboard buttons have this code :

```
NSMutableString *text = [textPad.text mutableCopy];
    NSRange selectedRange = textPad.selectedRange;

    [text replaceCharactersInRange:selectedRange withString:@"A"];
    textPad.text = text;
    [text release];
```

so the problem is when i want edit a word from middle of my sentence if i select a word and add some letters to that my button write only ONE Character  and if i write some other letters that begin end of sentence  ! what can i do to solve this problem ?

//EDIT//:
PROBLEM SOLVED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you need to set `selectedRange`. Also consider using convenience constructors rather than explicitly creating mutable copies — you only mutate it once so it's not likely to be any more efficient.

```
NSString *text = textPad.text;
NSRange selectedRange = textPad.selectedRange;
NSString *replacement = @"A";

text = [text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:selectedRange withString:replacement];
selectedRange = (NSRange){selectedRange.location + replacement.length, 0};

textPad.text = text;
textPad.selectedRange = selectedRange;
```

Comment: thank you but i changed your code works great ! there is no need      NSString *replacement = @"A";  and      selectedRange.length = replacement.length;

Comment: You need to update the "selected range" correctly. I made a mistake in my code (oops); it should be fixed now.